# Displaying data from a DataGridView on one Form into TextBoxes on another

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two forms. `ShoppingBasketForm.cs` and `EditBasketPopup.cs`.

`ShoppingBasketForm.cs` displays a shopping basket in a `DataGridView` called `dataGridBasket` which is bound to a seperate `List<OrderItem>OrderItems` which comes from my `OrderItem`class. This can be added to by filling in the provided text boxes/numericUpDowns on the page `Product Name` `Quantity` and `LatestPrice` and then clicking the `Add` button `btnAdd`. It also has the ability to remove data from the selected row by clicking the `Remove` button `btnRemove`.

I'm now trying to implement an `Edit` button `btnEdit` where once clicked, it instantiates the `EditBasketPopup` form. On this form there are the three text boxes/ numeric up downs displayed again `ProductName` `Quantity` and `LatestPrice`.

How do I take the data from the selected row on the `dataGridBasket` (User cannot select single cells) and use that to fill the three text boxes when the user activates the `btnEdit` click event?

I tried creating a properties inside the `EditBasketPopup.cs` to hold the data from the first form, but was unsure how to extract the data from the selected row in the `dataGridBasket` in string form and also came across the problem of needing the individual data from each cell in the row, seeing as they are bound to different properties.

I obviously don't have much example code for this question as it's a theory as to **how** rather than **why** but if you need anything just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Harry Sweetman ok first to get the selected element of your datagridview you can make something like this:

```
 //recover the view row
 DataGridViewRow drv = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridBasket.Current;

 //if the row is not empty => basket was selected in the dataGridView
 if (drv.Cells[0].Value != null)
 {
      //Here we get the first cell selected let say the name is like the id:
      string idBasketToEdit = drv.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Clone().ToString();

      //Now we instantiate the form EditBasketPopoup, but sending the selected basket as a parameter                  
       frmEdit = new EditBasketPopoup(idBasketToEdit);
       frmEdicion.Name = "Edit basket";
       frmEdicion.ShowDialog();         
 }
```

Also you need to have a form constructor in `EditBasketPopup.cs`  with a Basket parameter like this:

```
    public EditBasketPopup(string idBasket)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Basket b = control.GetBasket(idBasket);

        //You set the form boxes:
        txtProductName.Text = b.ProductName;
        txtLatestPrice.Text = b.LatestPrice;
        txtQuantity.Text = b.Quantity;
    }
```

Finally let s suppose you have a controller (Ex. BasketController) were you have some logic. Here it 's supposed that you search the Basket you want to edit on the collection that it 's binding your datagridview (dataGridBasket).

```
public Basket GetBasket(string idBasket)
{
    try
    {
        //basketCollection is the one that you use to bind dataGridBasket
        return basketCollection.Find(x => x.idBasket.Equals(idBasket));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you explain your first section of code a little more? I'm not quite understanding how it works. Thanks!

Comment: Could you also try and keep the same variable/form names I have used just for readability?

Comment: Where do `basketToEdit` and `Basket` come from?

Comment: @HarrySweetman and now? there you have `control.GetBasket(idBasket)` that should go to your BasketShopping controller and search for the basket you need to edit. it s ok?

Comment: `Control.GetBasket(idBasket)` returns an error for me, apparently `System.Windows.Forms.Control does not contain a definition for GetBasket`

Comment: i put it to you as an example is just the way you can get your Basket...
where do you have the baskets?

Comment: so finally... it worked? can you mark it as a solution?

Comment: The basket is just the data inside the `DataGridView`, it derives from an instantiation of my `ShoppingBasket` class, which contains the `List<OrderItem>OrderItems`